# Need Linq expression explanation

Tags: linq

I have a Linq expression that I do not understand 100%.
This Linq working on an image list. See below

```
ImagesList.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          .Select(int.Parse);
```

What does this do?

- `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` ?
- `.Select(int.Parse)`, does it returns only ONE figure or do it return a list of int values ?

Comment: can you show what is ImagesList ??

Comment: The above would transform a string such as `"12,54,23,9,43,,3,65,,2,5"` into `IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: What ImageList is is not very important here, since the code itself is quite self explanatory.. The OP doesn´t seem to need help to fix the code, but just to understand it

Answer (score 1):

```
new string[]
```

is creating an array of the list items, splitting it up with a comma (,)

```
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
```

removes the strings in the array that are empty, so that all array objects have a value

```
int.Parse
```

is there because the return value seems to be expected to be an integer(a number) in string form, so it is trying to change the datatype from string into int